# Alternative Jquery mouse event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright so the code below works fine if I click outside the #nav div. I was asking if it is possible to just move the mouse away from the #nav div to make it disappear. I don't want to 'click' to hide the div.

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $("#nav");

    if (container.has(e.target).length === 0)
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: you'll need to have a mouseenter to show and then you can use mouseleave to hide

Comment: The magic words are `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. There are already native events and jQuery methods for them. http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Comment: the mouseenter and mouseleave doesnt work :/

Comment: Yes they do. See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/SRMT8/

Comment: Serious man, have a look http://jsfiddle.net/sKpwV/ it doesnt work

Comment: If you actually use the code from the answer below, it works just fine -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/sKpwV/2/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign a function that hides the element on the `mouseleave` event.

```
$("#nav").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).hide(); 
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/SRMT8/